# On a line chart with a date axis, I want to label each time the "experiment" was checked with 1, 2, 3 etc

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

My data can be imagined as checking an experiment regularly, recording its values for the line graph, and recording the time it was checked. The times where the experiments were observed were irregular. Each observation was simultaneous and thus have the exact same time for all lines.

Problem is, I have a lot of observations. it's hard to figure out which observation it was in the middle of the line graph. How can I keep a date axis and its spacing, but also have an irregular axis labeling each check from start to finish "0, 1, 2, 3..."

Edit:

[this is the sample data I made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fgVF.png)

[this is the graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaeks.png)

[this is what I want it to be (can be put on the bottom instead of the top if needed)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trTlX.png)

[however, I don't want this, since it prevents a date axis and ruins the spacing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zbta.png)

Combo charts afaik also can't do what I want, since I want all the data on the same axis, and then just have observation labels that remain spaced irregularly.

Comment: Some of your text is contradictory, (i.e. either "The times where the experiments were observed were irregular" or "Each observation was simultaneous and thus have the exact same time for all lines" I don't see how both can apply...) Can you [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1351681/edit) your post to clarify and add some sample data, what your currently getting and what you would like to get?

Comment: I tried my best to word it, it's not really contradictory it's just hard to say in words.

I'll make some sample data soon. My actual chart has way, way too much data to be a practical example, so i'll have to make an example

Comment: Could you provide a simple sample or image about your problem?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad
I edited my post with images to help explain. the simultaneous times are just that data points align, but the times I checked were irregularly spaced in absolute units of time. It's really hard to put this into words but you'll see what i mean from the images.

Comment: @Lee I edited the post with images.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way.

I added a row for a set of hidden points which will have data labels with your observation numbers.

The first chart is basically the chart you started with. In the second chart I've added the Label series. In the third chart I've fixed the axis so the label series is along the top of the plot area, because Excel's autoscale added some space above the label series. In the fourth chart, I've added data labels to the label series; the default labels are above the points and show the Y values. In the fifth chart I've formatted the labels: they're larger and bold, centered on the points, and I've checked the Values From Cells option for what the labels show (and unchecked the Values option). Finally, in the sixth chart I've hidden the label series by formatting it with no line and no markers.

[image: add observation labels to your chart]

Alternatively, you could dispense with the added series, and use the Values From Cells option to label one or the other data series directly.

[image: add observation labels to your chart]